# Calculating the launch time of apps

Tags: ios, remote-debugging

I would like to compare the launch time of a few apps On the app store. Obviously I do not have access to source code, so I was wondering what is the best way to get accurate results ?

Is there a way to know when the system makes a call to applicationDidFinishLaunching (without source).

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video them starting up and look at the time codes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe fire up Instruments and look for some kind of timeline evidence with one of their profilers?